# controlling preventDefault on item inside of <a>

Tags: angularjs

**Here's how the code is setup :**

```
<a class="list-group-item" data-ng-click="displayProject()">
    <span class="icon" data-ng-click="showChildren()"><i class="icon ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i>&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="icon"><i class="icon ion-folder"></i></span>
    <span data-ng-bind="project.name"></span>
</a>
```

As you can see, I have everything wrapped in an `<a>` tag, and there's an `ng-click` event on it. Basically it displays the selected project in another view.

Inside the `<a>`, I have an icon with another `ng-click` event, in this case, displaying the children of the specific project.

Of course, if I click on the icon, the `displayProject()` event is called.

How would I go about cancelling / using `preventDefault` on the `<a>` tag when the icon is clicked?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an access to event by passing `$event` to ng-click callback.

```
<span class="icon" data-ng-click="showChildren($event)"><i class="icon ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i>&nbsp;</span>
```

and in `showChildren` method:

```
$event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: or maybe `stopPropagation()` in stead of `preventDefault()` should be called.